# User.findOne acting as User.Update in SailsJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, blueprint

I'm requesting the [blueprint](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-one) route `User.findOne` in SailsJs on the basis of user Id but it itself is calling `User.update`. Also, I just experienced a new thing that on sending multiple parameters to `findOne`, it updates the record on the basis of any single matched parameter. On the other hand, If i do create a controller named `user.findOne` and call the same route via controller, it works perfectly fine.

Is that the right behavior by SailsJs or I'm doing some mistake anywhere?

Comment: i have developed many project using SailsJs framework but i did not face any issue like you describe here. `User.findOne` only fetch record as par our query parameters.

Comment: @YogeshPatel Yeah this seems to be completely unusual and strange. I'm not getting any mistake/loop hole at my end, that's why posted here with a hope that probably someone more expert would be able to identify the issue.

Comment: you can ask in sails gitter. There are many exports of SailsJs.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, still wondering why is this happening,
I even tried creating an `update` function in my controller with some sample code but when I try hitting `findOne` from postman, it redirects me to my created `update` function.
Waiting for an answer on this serious issue.

However I found a solution by trying something like this (i.e. creating custom `findOne` function in the controller) and it worked:

```
findOne : function (req,res){
    var myReq = req.params.all();
    console.log(myReq);
    User.findOne(myReq, function UserFound(err, user){
        if (err) return res.negotiate("User not found!");

        else{
            console.log("I am getting here");
            console.log(user);
            return res.status(200).send(user);
        }
    })
}
```